# Adding test details to a VSTS / TFS test summary

Tags: c#, selenium, testing, tfs, azure-pipelines

I'm running automated Selenium tests and need to record some of the test details (username that was created, password etc) - how do I add these details to a VSTS / TFS test summary?

It seems like the Details section would be the ideal place, but I can't find a way to add data in there... I looked at using TestContext, but that didn't seem to provide this functionality.

[VSTS test summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvFRe.png)

Comment: The Test Result summary page doesn't support to customize. The Details couldn't be added data in it.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any way to do this. "Details" section is used to show the detailed information about the test step for Manual Run:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create a file during the of the details and add it as an attachment in the
["Attachments" section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQRC3.png)

you can do it using the REST API as explained in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/previous-apis/test/attachments?view=vsts